# Derivation for magnitude of acceleration of a body in orbit with general relativity coefficient?

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, orbital-motion

I came across an equation that an old professor used in an orbital simulation code and wanted to know how this equation was derived? I also wanted to know where $\alpha$ came from and what it represents in regards to general relativity.

$$a = \mu\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac{{\alpha}}{{r}^2}\right)}{{r}^2}\right)$$

where $\mu$ is (M1 + M2) times the gravitational constant G, and $\alpha$ is the parameter from general relativity.

I've tried googling it but haven't found the answer yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that definitely $\alpha^2/r^2$ and not $\alpha^2/r$? If it was $r$ instead of $r^2$ it would be the first order correction to the Newtonian force law.

Comment: Another possibility is $\alpha^2 = 6 L^2$, that would correspond to an effective pseudo-Newtonian term.

Comment: Hi thank you guys for your comments, I just checked and its actually just alpha and not alpha squared. However it was an r squared instead of an r, in reference to John's comment. 

Void, is there a resource where I can find the proof to that?